# converting rows into columns in t-sql - sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have situation that I have a table in the structure

```
ID, name
 1, 'value1'
 1, 'value2'
 2, 'value3'
 2, 'value4'
 1, 'value5'
```

I wanted to show the above data in following format

```
id , combineName
1  ,'value1','value2', 'value5'
2  ,'value3','value4'
```

Is there an easy way to do this in SQL Server 2005, or will I have to run cursors to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in aTable:

```
create  FUNCTION toCSV (@id int)

RETURNS varchar(100)

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @List varchar(100)

SELECT @List = COALESCE(@List + ', ', '') + 
   CAST(name AS varchar(10))

FROM aTable

WHERE ID = @id

RETURN(@list)

END;

go
```

Then:

select distinct id, dbo.toCSV(id) from aTable

Answer (score 1):

SQL 2005 has a PIVOT function that should do what you want.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Comment: You still need to know what columns you expect in advance, but given that pivot is your best bet.

Comment: Could someone show how to use PIVOT for this? Looking at his question, I don't see how. Even given a small finite set of values (1-10, say), he doesn't seem to want them to be aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using nested selects, or more easily using the pivot operator, although you have to know all of the possible values before hand.

If you want it to be dynamic, then you will need a cursor and some dynamic SQL.

Comment: rows could be dynamic, I can combine all rows into one column based on the id column.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Example of COALESCE Function:

Created one Temp table in which i have put one 9 rows with the help of WHILE loop.
The at the Main part i have just take Column to COALESCE function.

DROP TABLE #Material
SET NOCOUNT ON
CREATE TABLE #Material
(

```
MaterialID INT
```

)

DECLARE @LoopCounter INT
DECLARE @MaxLoopCounter INT

SET @LoopCounter = 1
SET @MaxLoopCounter = 10

WHILE (@LoopCounter < @MaxLoopCounter)
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO #Material (MaterialID) VALUES (@LoopCounter) 
SET @LoopCounter = @LoopCounter + 1
END

/* MAIN PART */
DECLARE @MaterialID VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @MaterialID = COALESCE(@MaterialID + ',','') + CAST(MaterialID AS VARCHAR(100)) FROM #Material

PRINT 'FINAL OUTPUT: '+ @MaterialID

-- SELECT * FROM #Material
SET NOCOUNT OFF