# How do i transform rows into columns in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655197/converting-rows-into-columns-in-t-sql-sql-server-2005) here in stackoverflow with the same title but that is not what I am looking for.
I have a table like the one below

```
Name   | Count  
----------------    
Chery  | 257  
Drew   | 1500
Morgon | 13  
Kath   | 500  
Kirk   | 200  
Matt   | 76
```

I need to trasform this result set into something like this

```
Chery | Drew | Morgon | Kath | Kirk | Matt  
-------------------------------------------  
257     1500     13      500    200    76
```

How do i acheive this using sql server 2005?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There are similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946234/convert-database-rows-into-columns),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801895/sql-server-convert-rows-to-columns) answered in stackoverflow.**

You need to use the operator **[PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)** in your query to acheive this.Here is the example and explanation on how you can do that.The example is referenced from **[this](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx)** source.

```
---I assumed your tablename as TESTTABLE---
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)

SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT
                                '],[' + t.Name
                        FROM    TESTTABLE AS t
                        ORDER BY '],[' + t.Name
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                      ), 1, 2, '') + ']'

SET @query = N'SELECT '+ @cols +' FROM
(SELECT t1.Name , t1.Count FROM TESTTABLE AS t1) p
PIVOT (MAX([Count]) FOR Name IN ( '+ @cols +' ))
AS pvt;'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

**Explanation**

1.The first part of the query

```
SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT
                        '],[' + t.Name
                FROM TESTTABLE AS t
                ORDER BY '],[' + t.Name
                FOR XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 2, '') + ']'
```

gives you a nice flattened result of your Name column values in a single row as follow

```
[Cheryl],[Drew],[Karen],[Kath],[Kirk],[Matt]
```

**You can learn more about the STUFF and XML PATH [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345137SQL.90.aspx).**

2.`SELECT + @cols + FROM` will select all the rows as coloumn names for the final result set (pvt - step 3)

i.e

```
Select [Chery],[Drew],[Morgan],[Kath],[Kirk],[Matt]
```

3.This query pulls all the rows of data that we need to create the cross-tab results.  The (p) after the query is creating a temporary table of the results that can then be used to satisfy the query for step 1.

```
(SELECT t1.Name, t1.Count FROM  TESTTABLE AS t1) p
```

4.The PIVOT expression

```
PIVOT (MAX (Count) FOR Name IN ( @cols) AS pvt
```

does the actual summarization and puts the results into a temporary table called pvt as

```
Chery | Drew | Morgon | Kath | Kirk | Matt  
-------------------------------------------  
257     1500     13      500    200    76
```

Comment: +1, great solution and answer.  note, the `TOP 100 PERCENT` can be changed to `TOP 30` or whatever, so you don't exceed the number of columns if you have a lot of rows.

Answer (score 2):

See [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx).

> You can use the `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT`
>   relational operators to change a
>   table-valued expression into another
>   table. `PIVOT` rotates a table-valued
>   expression by turning the unique
>   values from one column in the
>   expression into multiple columns in
>   the output, and performs aggregations
>   where they are required on any
>   remaining column values that are
>   wanted in the final output. `UNPIVOT`
>   performs the opposite operation to
>   PIVOT by rotating columns of a
>   table-valued expression into column
>   values.

The quick answer is

```
SELECT Chery, Drew, Morgon, Kath, Kirk, Matt
FROM 
(SELECT [Name], [Count] From Foo)
PIVOT
(
   MIN([Count])
   FOR [Name] IN (Chery, Drew, Morgon, Kath, Kirk, Matt)
) AS PivotTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid anything complicated like a pivot or the accepted answer, you can do this! (most of the code is just setting up the test data just in case anyone wants to try it)

```
/* set up your test table */
declare @TestData table (Name Varchar(80),[Count] int)    
insert into @TestData (Name, [count])
Select 'Chery' as name, 257 as [count]  
union all select 'Drew', 1500
union all select 'Morgon',13  
union all select 'Kath', 500  
union all select 'Kirk', 200  
union all select 'Matt', 76 

/* the query */
Declare @Query Varchar(max)
Select @Query=Coalesce(@query+', ','SELECT ') +Convert(VarChar(5),[count]) +' as ['+name+']'
from @TestData
Execute (@Query)
/* result 

Chery       Drew        Morgon      Kath        Kirk        Matt
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
257         1500        13          500         200         76

*/
```