# Aggregate list of users and values into a table with list of users and counts of values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of users with three columns.

```
Username    Accepted    Rejected 

User 1      1            NULL 
User 1      1            NULL 
User 1      NULL         1
User 2      1            1
User 3      1            NULL 
User 3      1            NULL 
User 2      NULL         1
User 3      NULL         NULL 
User 2      NULL         NULL
```

I'd like to show a list of all the users with counts of Accepted/Rejected columns like so:

```
Username    Accepted    Rejected 
User 1      2           1
User 2      1           2
User 3      2           NULL
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you reviewed the documentation for COUNT() and SUM()?

Comment: I tried with CASE and GROUP BY, but not there yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Accepted and Rejected can contain 1, 0 and null only use sum because sum will return null if all values supplied are null:

```
select UserName, 
       sum(Accepted) Accepted,
       sum(Rejected) Rejected
  from ATable
 group by UserName
```

Count will return zero in Rejected column of user3.

Comment: Nikola, your solution looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723157/how-can-i-turn-a-bunch-of-rows-into-aggregated-columns-without-using-pivot-in-sq which I am trying. It looks like it will get me there. Count is probably better as I show rows in a SSRS report tablix only if both Accepted and Rejected are not 0 values.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT 
    u.username,
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(u.accepted) = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE
        COUNT(u.accepted) 
    END AS Accepted,
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(u.rejected) = 0 THEN NULL 
    ELSE 
        COUNT(u.rejected)
    END AS Rejected
FROM
    usr1 u

GROUP BY u.username