# Fetch data in a single Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables PackageDetail and PackageDuration
PackageDuration have the PackageID as Foreign Key i.e. can have multiple records with respect to PackageID

The Schema of the PackageDetail is:

```
PackageID  INT PK
PackageName Nvarchar(50)
```

Schema of the PackageDuration Table is:

```
DurationID INT PK
Price   Money
Duration Nvarchar(50)
PackageID INT FPK
```

PackageDetail tables have follwoing records:

```
PackageID        PackageName
  1              TestPackage
  2              MySecondPackage
```

PackageDuration table have following records:

```
DurationID      PackageID    Price        Duration
  1                 1        100          6
  2                 1        200          12
  3                 1        300          24
  4                 2        500          6
```

PackageDuration table can have max 3 records with one PackageID not more than this(if have ignore that)
Now I want to select the Records as in following Way:

```
PackageId  PackageNAme     Price1 Price2 Price3 Duration1  Duration2    Duration3
1          TestPackage        100    200    300         6         12           24
2          MySecondPackage    500   null   null         6       null         null
```

Please suggest me how can I achive this.

Comment: What if PackageID 1 has 4 prices? Do you need to dynamically add columns for Price4 and Duration4?

Comment: yes, A package can have max 3 price based on the Duration 6Month, 12(1 year), 24(2 years)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach:

```
WITH Durations AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PackageId ORDER BY DurationId) Sequence
    FROM PackageDuration 
)

SELECT  A.PackageId, B.PackageName, 
        MIN(CASE WHEN Sequence = 1 THEN Price ELSE NULL END) Price1,
        MIN(CASE WHEN Sequence = 2 THEN Price ELSE NULL END) Price2,
        MIN(CASE WHEN Sequence = 3 THEN Price ELSE NULL END) Price3,
        MIN(CASE WHEN Sequence = 1 THEN Duration ELSE NULL END) Duration1,
        MIN(CASE WHEN Sequence = 2 THEN Duration ELSE NULL END) Duration2,
        MIN(CASE WHEN Sequence = 3 THEN Duration ELSE NULL END) Duration3
FROM Durations A
INNER JOIN PackageDetail B
ON A.PackageId = B.PackageId
GROUP BY A.PackageId, B.PackageName
```

Comment: +1 I like this one best, for there are no hard coded values. You know, (requirement) constants may change over time... One year from now: "You know, we should change the duration values. Where are those defined again?"

Answer (score 1):

This should work as long as the durations are unique for a package and they are either 6, 12, or 24.

```
SELECT 
    PackageDetail.PackageId, PackageDetail.PackageName, 
    D1.Price as Price1, D2.Price as Price2, D3.Price as Price3,
    D1.Duration as Duration1, D2.Duration as Duration2, D3.Duration as Duration3
FROM PackageDetail
LEFT OUTER JOIN PackageDuration D1 
    ON D1.PackageId = PackageDetail.PackageId AND D1.Duration = 6
LEFT OUTER JOIN PackageDuration D2 
    ON D2.PackageId = PackageDetail.PackageId AND D2.Duration = 12
LEFT OUTER JOIN PackageDuration D3 
    ON D3.PackageId = PackageDetail.PackageId AND D3.Duration = 24
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH pvt AS
(
   SELECT PackageID,
      Price1 = MAX(CASE WHEN Duration = 6 THEN Price END),
      Price2 = MAX(CASE WHEN Duration = 12 THEN Price END),
      Price3 = MAX(CASE WHEN Duration = 24 THEN Price END),
      Duration1 = MAX(CASE WHEN Duration = 6 THEN 6 END),
      Duration2 = MAX(CASE WHEN Duration = 12 THEN 12 END),
      Duration3 = MAX(CASE WHEN Duration = 24 THEN 24 END)
   FROM dbo.PackageDuration
   GROUP BY PackageID
)
SELECT
   pvt.PackageID,
   p.PackageName,
   pvt.Price1, pvt.Price2, pvt.Price3,
   pvt.Duration1, pvt.Duration2, pvt.Duration3
FROM
   dbo.PackageDetail AS p
INNER JOIN 
   pvt ON p.PackageID = pvt.PackageID
ORDER BY p.PackageID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something in the requirements, but it seems like Sql Server's [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) is what you're looking for.

There are [quite a few questions here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server+pivot) about PIVOT... Here's a good clean example with references to other questions: [How do i transform rows into columns in sql server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344590/how-do-i-transform-rows-into-columns-in-sql-server-2005)

The big benefit of a pivot table over the other answers here is that it will scale out with no modifications if you add records to your `PackageDuration` table in the future.

Comment: I started to work on a solution using PIVOT but there are a couple of issues with the desired output that will make PIVOT more convoluted than necessary. If only the first 4 columns were required it would be much more intuitive to write using PIVOT...